# Android Image is not proportionate for phone and Tablet size

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to display a imageview and 2 textview using listfragment. I design it for the purpose of displaying on Tablet. It looks ok. However, if i use phone to view it, the effect is different. As you can see from the screenshot .

[image]

Is it possible to make the phone view is same as the Tablet view?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:src="@drawable/img_1"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Name"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Price"
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can't find the screenshot.

Comment: the screenshot URL is http://i.stack.imgur.com/qjLp5.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same thing and I came to know about sdp which changes according to the device [try this](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)
Or you can make a separate layout for different screen sizes by [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)`

Comment: do you find the solution??

Comment: if i copy and paste my code into their layout, its the same effect.

Comment: Just use sdp in place of dp

Comment: have you tested the app in different size device??

Comment: yes, i did. looks the same.  How about u use the code i paste in the question to see the result ?

Comment: I made separate layout  based on the side width and it worked  but I have not use the library in any tab but i tried in different devices